# Cannot get Razor syntax to work when nested Razor statements are there

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have following code in MVC4 ASP.Net with Razor engine, but there is some issue with the nested if for the 'tr' element.

**Question**: What would be the correct way of emitting the string "pink" if variable 'i' was even and if variable 'i' was odd then emit the string "white"? I wanted to use Razor syntax to do this rather than use even-odd CSS styling of tr.

```
   @{
        int i = 0;
    }
    @foreach (Product p in Model)
    {
        i++;

        <tr style="background-color:@if(i%2==0){"pink"} else { "white"})">
            <td>@p.Id</td>
            <td style="text-align:left;">@p.Name</td>
            <td style="text-align:left;">@p.Description</td>
            <td>@p.Price</td>
            <td>@p.UnitsInStock</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@(i % 2 == 0 ? "pink" : "white")
```

Comment: I used a single equal sign instead of a double one. Try again.

Comment: Yes it works now. Thanks. Can I mark 2 answers here?

Comment: I am afraid not. You have to chose what works best for you so other visitors know. You may upvote all you want though.

Comment: @Sunil, Giannis got in first (and its more concise) so mark this one as accepted, but out of curiosity, why not use css?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I have the CSS solution, but I just like the code-based solution which is  guaranteed to be browser independent even though modern browsers are all excellent nowadays . I think, its more of a personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

```
@{
  int i = 0;
  var bc = "white";
}
@foreach (Product p in Model)
{
  if (i % 2 == 0)
  {
    bc= "pink";
  }
  <tr style="background-color:@bc" ...>
```

}